# Magento and Click & Drop integration

Tags: web-services, magento-1.9

I am trying to integrate my magento v1.9 store with click & drop. But when I make connection it will show "Connection to your marketplace failed. Please check your details and try again".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Magento 1 we found that being able to set the WS-I compliance solved this by making the Click and Drop system compatible with Magento API service.

```
Go to -
'System>Configuration>Services>Magento Core API'
```

and under `General Settings` change the `WS-I Compliance` from Yes to No.

Now your Magento API will be compatible with Click and Drop.
Works for Magento 1.x. No idea how to do it for Magento 2!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set up Magento API credentials correctly and all required resources have been allowed in selected user group

```
System->Web-Services->SOAP/XML RPC - Users

System->Web-Services->SOAP/XML RPC - Roles
```

Comment: also give API key and user name. but my server reject the Click & Drop request

Answer (score 0):

Check SOAP PHP Extension is enabled for the PHP Version running on Server.